# warning prometheus alert for rabbitmq queue space left

Tags: rabbitmq, prometheus, metrics

Can you help me with  **Prometheus expression alert** that can monitor the **space left of a specific rabbitmq queue**?

For example, I have couple of rabbitmq queues with "x-max-length-bytes"= 115747500 bytes":

```
   # rabbitmqctl -p v-host list_queues name arguments | grep 115747500
    queue-test1    [{"x-max-length-bytes",115747500 }]
    queue-test2    [{"x-dead-letter-exchange",[]},{"x-message-ttl",604800000},{"x-max-length-bytes",115747500 }]
    queue-test3    [{"x-max-length-bytes",115747500 }]
    queue-test4    [{"x-dead-letter-exchange",[]},{"x-message-ttl",604800000},{"x-max-length-bytes",115747500 }]
    queue-test5    [{"x-max-length-bytes",115747500 }]
    queue-test6    [{"x-dead-letter-exchange",[]},{"x-message-ttl",604800000},{"x-max-length-bytes",115747500 }]




    # rabbitmqctl -p v-host list_queues

      test1   471
      test2   4163
      test3   0
      test4   2466
      test5   0
      test6   0
```

I found on the google that the **max_message_size**  for Rabbitmq is **32768 bytes**, so I thought if I can have the below math expression:

```
(max_message_size(32768 bytes) * number queue messages) - x-max-length-bytes ( 115747500 bytes) = total_space_left_in_queue_bytes 
 if total_space_left_in_queue_bytes > 90% = send warning
```

Comment: Do you have Prometheus and exporter for rabbit installed and configured? And does said exporter exposes metrics corresponding to fields you expect to use in your alert rule?

Comment: the exposes metrics doesn't correspond with the one I want , I mean I don't have any metric regarding the space left of the rabbitmq metric.

Comment: And do you have metrics for max_message_size, "number queue messages", and x-max-length-bytes?

Comment: no, I don't have these metrics

Comment: It seems like default exporter exposes some metrics related to total size of messages: look near `rabbitmq_detailed_queue_messages_persistent_bytes` at https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html#health-indicators. `x-max-length-bytes` feels like a configuration option, so probably you can replace it with constant in the rule.